# Overriding and printing classes

Tags: java, overriding

I'm just trying to Override and use the toString method to print some information about my classes.

Can someone please provide advice as to how I would do this?

I've never done this before, and I'm becoming stuck.

My Base Class:

```
public class Vehicle {
  int seatNumber;
  int numberMade;
  int yearMade;

  public Vehicle(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade) {
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
    this.numberMade = numberMade;
    this.yearMade = yearMade;
  }

  public int getSeatNumber() {
    return seatNumber;
  }

  public int getNumberMade() {
    return numberMade;
  }

  public int getYearMade() {
    return yearMade;
  }
}
```

A derived class:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public int topSpeed;

  public Car(int seatNumber, int numberMade, int yearMade, int topSpeed) {
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber; //takes the value you pass as parameter
    this.numberMade = numberMade; // and stores it into the instance variable
    this.yearMade= yearMade;
    this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
  }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Assignment2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myCar = new Car(5, 20000, 1998, 180);
    Motorbike myMotorbike = new Motorbike(1, 5000, 2015, 300);

    System.out.println(myCar);
    System.out.println(myMotorbike);
  }
}
```

Comment: And where did you try to put `toString`?

Comment: Just ovveride `toString()` method in your classes and you are done.

Comment: Advice: Instead of assigning directly to the `seatNumber`, `numberMade` and `yearMade`, make them `private` and call the `super` constructor to give them values. Now devise a `toString` method that represents `Vehicle`. Doing the above might give you a hint on a proper way to building `toString` for `Car` (based on the relationship between `Vehicle` and `Car`).

Comment: I'm 90% certain there are hundreds of java `toString()` questions on SO...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Vehicle {

  int seatNumber;
  int numberMade;
  int yearMade;

  // Getters, setters, constructor, etc

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return String.format("[Vehicle] seats: %d, number made: %d, yearMade %d", seatNumber, numberMade, yearMade);
  }
}
```

Same for the other Class

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just trying to Override and use the toString method to print some information about my classes

There are 2 ways you can override a method in the subclass.

- Override by modification
- Override it with new implementation

> Can someone please provide advice as to how I would do this?

Overridding in Java is very simple. Just rewrite the method with similar method signature in the subclass according to the method in its super class.

Below shows an example of overriding by **modification**:

```
class Animal
{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "An animal";
    }
}

class CatFamily extends Animal{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + " from the cat family.";
    }
}

class Lion extends CatFamily{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + " - A Lion";
    }
}
```

Create a super & subclass instance for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    System.out.println(new Animal());        
    System.out.println(new CatFamily());        
    System.out.println(new Lion());        
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
An animal
An animal from the cat family.
An animal from the cat family. - A Lion
```